# Is the skill check for axii static in conversations?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I have been playing for a while now, but I'm not sure how the skill check with axii in conversation works. The description for the delusion skill says

> Also increases the effectiveness of Axii in dialogues.

Does this mean that I will always succeed with axii against weaker opponents, or that I only have a higher chance of succeeding? That would mean that there is a chance of failure even against the weaker opponents.

I'm not that far in the game so I haven't encountered (in my opinion) strong willed characters that had the option available during a conversation so I could test this. With one point in delusion the skill seems to always work against the thug outside the first tavern in White Orchard.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no chance involved. Each Axii conversation option has a difficulty rating, ranging between 1 and 5. Your base Axii skill is 1, each level of delusion increases your skill level by 1 up to a maximum of 4.

If your skill level matches or exceeds the difficulty you succeed with your Axii use, otherwise you fail. And yes, there are a few difficulty 5 Axii checks, which will always fail, mostly when multiple people are involved.

Maxing delusion is helpful, as it makes several dialogues easier and also nets you 40 exp every time it suceeds, but it may also cause you to skip a bit of content at times, as you solve the problem with a literal wave of the hand.

Comment: I suppose this also means that any Axii intensity bonuses are useless in this regard.

Comment: @VilleP In terms of dialogue, yes. Axii intensity increases your success chance with Axiis primary use, stunning or mindcontrolling enemies in combat.

Comment: Does the game even implement positive solution to the difficulty 5 checks? (e.g. in case you increase the maximum skill level through mods)

Comment: @SF. No. Those Axii checks are designed to always fail, so it doesn't make a lot of sense to implement a positive outcome. Keep in mind, that the model I presented in the answer isn't necessarily the exact way it is implemented in the games code. Those difficulty 5 checks may very well just lead to a fail no matter how high your Axii skill is.